# delay between fadein/fadeout jquery

Tags: jquery, delay, fadein, fadeout

I have made a simple loop that makes div#1 fade in/out and then div#2 fade in/out
The code i have written is like this:

```
function runToggle(iDuration, domFirst,domSecond) {
        $(domFirst).fadeToggle(iDuration, "linear",function() {
          $(domFirst).fadeToggle(iDuration, "linear",function() {
            $(domSecond).fadeToggle(iDuration,"linear",function() {
              $(domSecond).fadeToggle(iDuration,"linear",function() {
                  setTimeout(function() {
                      runToggle(iDuration, domFirst,domSecond) ;
                  },50);
              });
            }); 
          });
       }); 
};

runToggle(2000, $('#box1'),$('#box2'));
```

But i cant seem to make a delay inbetween each fade in and out... (logically what i want is this: div1 Fade in, Delay, div1 Fade out, div2 fade in, delay, div2 fade out and then start all over again.

Comment: You might find the aptly named [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery has a built in `.delay()` function. (see the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/delay/))

Change all of these lines:

`$(domFirst).fadeToggle(iDuration, "linear",function() {`

to:

`$(domFirst).delay(200).fadeToggle(iDuration, "linear",function() {`

Comment: same thing i tried - but for some reason it didnt work before - but does now. i propably made a typo some where! thanks! :-)